# Multiprocessing not working only single process is running on server

Tags: python, solr, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am calling a **Solr RestAPI** to extract the result. I have **multiple calls** on Solr. So, I am using **multiprocessing** to do parallel calling on Solr RestAPI.

I have attached a piece of code where I am **passing** a list of **chunk_query** to function **checkTermInSolr**. The **problem** is that I am able to see the **list of processes** are **displaying** but they **don't** seems to be **running**. Only a **single process** is **running** and rest are **not**.

**Piece of Code:**

```
chunk_query = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
results = pool.map_async(self.solr_obj.checkTermInSolr, [qry_part for qry_part in chunk_query])
pprint(results.get())
```

**Number of Processes running** for python program and **don't** seems to be **working/running**. Only the first **one process** is **running** properly while **others** are **not**.

```
root     39005  1.5  0.1 470052 30620 pts/3    Sl+  16:43   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39006  0.0  0.0 250952 24596 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39007  0.0  0.0 250952 24596 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39008  0.0  0.0 250952 24600 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39009  0.0  0.0 250952 24504 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39010  0.0  0.0 250952 24608 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39011  0.0  0.0 250952 24608 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39012  0.0  0.0 250952 24608 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39013  0.0  0.0 248600 23528 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39014  0.0  0.0 248856 23540 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
root     39015  0.0  0.0 248856 23540 pts/3    S+   16:44   0:00 python querysearch_mp.py
```

Am I doing something wrong with multiprocessing or anything else?